# ngx-bootstrap Custom typeahead not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a custom typeahead that searches my API every time the user types something but its not working. Its not even entering the `autocomplete()` function. I'm using Angular 4 CLI (1.4.2), bootstrap 4, and ngx-bootstrap (1.9.3). What am I doing wrong?

component.ts

```
public autoCompleteRef = this.autoComplete.bind(this);

public autoComplete() {
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    searchParams.set('search', this.autoCompleteSearchTerm);

    return this.http.get(this.api_url, {search: searchParams, headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map((el)=> {
            return el.map((data)=> {
                return ({id: data.id, name: data.name});
            });
        })
        .toPromise();
}

public typeaheadOnSelect(e): void {
    console.log('Selected value: ', e.value);
}
```

html

```
<input class="form-control"
       [(ngModel)]="autoCompleteSearchTerm"
       [typeahead]="autoCompleteRef"
       [typeaheadOptionField]="'name'"
       [typeaheadWaitMs]="300"
       [typeaheadMinLength]="1"
       (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Call that function with (keyup). That will do the trick.
And whenever the user types a character, it will call the API and store the result in a variable, that variable will be passed as `[typeahead]="autoCompleteRef"`.

Call the function something like:

```
<input class="form-control"
       [(ngModel)]="autoCompleteSearchTerm"
       [typeahead]="autoCompleteRef"
       [typeaheadOptionField]="'name'"
       [typeaheadWaitMs]="300"
       [typeaheadMinLength]="1"
       (keyup)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)">
```